# Physics Animation Sequence with Transparent Plane

Tags: animation, transparency

I would like to save my physics animation in a PNG sequence with the landing plane transparent.  I have an object that is landing on a plane.  This plane needs to be transparent in the PNG animation sequence.  I've seen posts with the "Film" tab, but I don't seem to have this in verion 2.79a.  How do I do this?  Thank you.

Comment: As stated, I don't have the "Film" tab.  That post refers to an older version, I'm assuming.

Comment: Yes you do. You are either not looking in the right place or have the wrong render engine active. If you don't then edit your question and provide screenshots to back your claim so that we don't have to guess in the dark what your issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Film tab appears with Cycles Renderer (here v2.79a):
[image]

The "Transparent" option in Film tab is for the background only. For any mesh to be transparent as well, you have several options. Make sure you select RGBA in the PNG options in order to include the transparency.

1. define the material to be transparent:
   [image]
2. uncheck the object from rendering:
   [image]
3. make it invisible to camera:
   [image]

I am sure I am missing some other means! Note that all those methods may have side effect like shadows etc.

Comment: Awesome, but how does it distinguish which Plane is transparent?

Comment: See, one of the Planes is the "ground" of my animation, which includes gravity.  The objects fall and bounce on the Plane.  I need that Plane to be transparent for the PNG animation sequencing.

Comment: see additional info in my edits

Comment: Sorry, but that's just making the plane gray.

Comment: Is there some way I can save this project and let you download it to take a look to see what I am missing?

Comment: Please attach sreenshots of your attempts and flesh out the description of the steps taken (with the "edit" link). This will kill 2 birds with one stone: help the next viewer who may have the same problem and increase the chance of someone addressing it.